# .NET MenuStrip with native Windows renderer?

Tags: .net, native, look-and-feel, menustrip

Does anyone know how to have the MenuStrips to rendered with native Windows look and feel depending the OS version the user is using?

The current renders don't do it...

I'm currently using a third party control that can do it but uses MainMenu and ContextMenu instead of what I'm looking for, the MenuStrip...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone else pointed me one, here it is for anyone interested:
http://code.google.com/p/szotar/source/browse/trunk/Client/Szotar.WindowsForms/Base/NativeToolStripRenderer.cs