# Getting WinForms menus and toolbars to use the system theme?

Tags: winforms, themes, accessibility, preferences, toolstrip

Is there a way to get WinForms controls `MenuStrip` and `ToolStrip` to rendering using the current system theme?

---

Normally the WinForms `MenuStrip` and `ToolStrip` controls have a [`RenderMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.rendermode.aspx) property, which points to a class that handles the rendering:

- [`ToolStripSystemRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsystemrenderer.aspx)

  [image]
- [`ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.aspx)

  [image]
- [`ManagerRenderMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.rendermode.aspx)

  which defaults to whatever `ToolStripManager.Renderer` uses (i.e. **Professional** or **System**)

Neither of these renderers use the Windows system theme:

[image]

How can i get a .NET WinForms `MenuStrip` and `ToolStrip` control to use the system theme?

---

i could ask some related, but different, questions:

- does the .NET FCL contain a [`ToolStripRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.aspx) that implements "system" rendering?
- has anyone written a `ToolStripRenderer` that implements "system" rendering?

Comment: Similar question with answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204041/net-menustrip-with-native-windows-renderer

Answer (score 0):

hey i know its not exectly the answer you where looking for but telerik already did what you want,
i used there library and works great, so you can go either way you can use there library or maybe get some ideas from it here is there [home page about winforms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)

hope this helps.